Live preview extension not working correctly
I have been using live preview for some weeks and it was working good but now it's not automatically showing the changes , it's not automatically refreshing
I tried to see the changes when i type something in html file or make any other changes but it remains static .

You are using prerelease bits, so any issue should be reported to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-livepreview/issues

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
